# choicemodelr: Error in Ops.data.frame: '==' only defined for equally-sized data frames

Tags: r, bayesian

I am analyzing data from a conjoint (test data) to get prepared for real data.

The data file has the form as required (UnitID Set Alt X_1 ... X_natts y) were y is discrete. In each choice set I have 3 alternatives (alt: 1-3) as well as a no choice option (alt: 4). The independent variables are effect coded (1, 0, -1). As far as I can see, that data are in the required format.

However, I can’t estimate the coefficients. If I run the model without demographic variables I get the following error:

> Error in Ops.data.frame(data[, 1], ID[i]) :
> ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Using the demographic variables I get the following:

> Error: number of rows in demos does not equal number of units

I do not find an error explanation in the internet so far and does not know how to solve this issue. I guess, it is a simple mistake in the data file that I do not see. I already tried to use a different coding but I get the same errors. Here is the code I use:

```
> xcoding=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
> mcmc = list(R = 20000, use = 10000)  
> options = list(none=FALSE, save=TRUE, keep=1)
> out = choicemodelr(data=robottest_bayes, xcoding, mcmc = mcmc, options = options)
> #with demographic variables
> out = choicemodelr(data=robottest_bayes, demos=robottest_bayes_demo, xcoding, mcmc = mcmc, options = options)
```

The data files are the following:

```
    > show(robottest_bayes)
# A tibble: 8,464 × 18
   respid  ques   alt apperance_burly apperance_intelligent apperance_pink features_car features_laundry features_compute
    <int> <int> <int>           <int>                 <int>          <int>        <int>            <int>            <int>
1       1     1     1               1                     0              0            1                0                0
2       1     1     2               0                     1              0            0                1                0
3       1     1     3               0                     0              1            0                0                1
4       1     1     4               0                     0              0            0                0                0
5       1     2     1               0                     1              0            0                0                0
6       1     2     2               0                     0              1            0                0                0
7       1     2     3               1                     0              0            0                0                0
8       1     2     4               0                     0              0            0                0                0
9       1     3     1               0                     0              1            0                0                0
10      1     3     2               1                     0              0            0                0                0
# ... with 8,454 more rows, and 9 more variables: features_dog <int>, features_vaccuum <int>, features_splines <int>,
#   brand_botpro <int>, brand_gizmobot <int>, price_10 <int>, price_11 <int>, nochoice <int>, choice <int>

> show(robottest_bayes_demo)
# A tibble: 529 × 3
   respid   sex   age
    <int> <int> <int>
1       1     0    42
2       2     0    55
3       3     0    37
4       4     0    35
5       5     1    41
6       6     1    35
7       7     0    56
8       8     0    27
9       9     1    36
10     10     1    42
# ... with 519 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to exclude the rows of no choice option from the data file, and amend the script as:

```
options = list(none=TRUE, save=TRUE, keep=1)
```

As you have 3 alternatives, for the choice set which the respondent chose the "no choice option", the choice number will be "number of alternatives +1", that is, 4. The ChoiceModelR will recognise that the "no choice option" is selected.

According to p. 5 of the vignette of ChoiceModelR,

> none: set to TRUE to estimate a none parameter, and the data does not include a row for “none” (i.e., no choice) (default is FALSE).

Try whether it works.