# ChoiceModelR package for conjoint analysis in R error: estimating betas

Tags: r, bayesian, multinomial

I've run a conjoint study and now trying to use R package [ChoiceModelR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChoiceModelR/ChoiceModelR.pdf) to estimate utilities. I've read the package documentation and looked through similar answers/questions on StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606465/choicemodelr-error-in-data-structure) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85362/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-choicemodelr-rhiermnlrwmixture-in-r/86102#86102)), but getting the error message below.

My data file (the .csv that you can download from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VhosD_EFJpTs_qV4KzsuR6aHp_HvWI5s/view?usp=sharing) has the required format (UnitID Set Alt X_1 ... X_natts y) were y is discrete. In each choice set, I have 2 alternatives and "none" choice. I have excluded the rows with the "none" option from the data file. For the "none" choice set, the choice number is set as "number of alternatives +1", that is, 3.

As far as I can see, that data is in the required format. However, I can’t estimate the utilities and get the following error:

```
Error: invalid values of y present in data - values must be 1 to 3
```

My input looks like this:

```
id    set_number card_number att1 att2 att3 att4 dv
1 932          1           1    1    1    1    3  2
2 932          1           2    2    2    4    4  0
4 932          2           1    3    3    3    1  2
5 932          2           2    4    2    2    4  0
7 932          3           1    5    4    1    3  2
8 932          3           2    6    3    3    2  0
...
```

My code looks like this

```
library(ChoiceModelR)

c_data <- read.csv("c_data.csv")

# Set parameter for calculation
# R is the total number of iterations of the Markov Chain Monte Carlo to be performed
# use is the number of iterations to be used in parameter estimation 

mcmc = list(R = 4000, use = 2000)

# Set parameter of datainput
# xcoding specifies the way in which each attribute will be coded (0 = categorical, 1 = nominal)
# none = TRUE to estimate a none parameter, and the data does not include a row for “none” (i.e., no choice)
# keep is the thinning parameter that defines the number of random draws to save

xcoding = c(0, 0, 0, 0)
options = list(none = TRUE, keep = 5)

# Putting it together to get betas
choicemodelr(data = c_data, xcoding = xcoding, mcmc = mcmc, options = options)
```

Running this code results in this error:

```
Error: invalid values of y present in data - values must be 1 to 3
```

20 top rows with dput:

```
structure(list(id = c(932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 
932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 933L, 933L, 
933L, 933L), set_number = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), card_number = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), att1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L), att2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L), att3 = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L), att4 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
    dv = c(2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would really appreciate any advice here.

Comment: Cannot say what your trouble was, but just for future readers who come here like I did looking for help, in my case a similar error message was because I had "None" encoded as "0" instead of as 1+the number of options.  For example, if there are three options, then "None" should be coded as "4", not as "0".